# What exactly does ordfilt2 do?

Tags: matlab, filtering

Can you please explain in simple terms what do the input parameters indicate in the [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) function in matlab?

```
B=ordfilt2(A,Order,Domain)
```

I have seen people use this function as `J = ordfilt2(I, 9, true(5))` or `J=ordfilt2(I,25,ones(3,3))`

But I do not understand what each input does to the image `I` to give `J` as output..

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: [RTFM?](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html)  Perhaps if you could explain what you do not understand about the manual entry?

Comment: In this example you used a [1 1; 1 1] matrix as your domain. What if you had a matrix that's either [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0] or [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]. Actually, my question is: how do the zero elements affect the filter output?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty new to this myself, so please correct me if I get this wrong.

Using your example, `J = ordfilt2(I, 9, true(5))`.
`ordfilt2` will move over the 2d array `I` in blocks of the same size as `true(5)`. For each of these 5x5 blocks, sort all the elements from smallest to largest. Now fill in the corresponding block in `J` with a bunch of copies of the 9th smallest element.

To use a smaller example, so I have room to type it:

```
I = [ 1 2 4 5 ;
      5 3 5 1 ;
      0 3 5 2 ;
      2 1 7 7 ];
J = ordfilt2(I,3, ones(2,2));
```

Now, let's go through a few blocks one at a time. The first `ones(2,2)` block is `[1 2; 5 3]` in the top left corner. If we sort these elements, we get `[1 2 3 5]`, and since we're looking for the 3rd smallest, we receive a value of 3 for the (1,1) position of `J`.

```
J = [ 3 ? ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ];
```

next up is the `I(1:2,2:3)` block. Ordering those elements gives `[2 3 4 5]`, so the third smallest is 4. Now we replace `J(1,2)` with a 4.

```
J = [ 3 4 ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ;
      ? ? ? ? ];
```

Go ahead and run this command and compare I, J to understand what's happening. One other thing to know is that the input matrix is padded by default with zeros at the lower and right sides. So the `I(4:5,4:5)` block is `[ 7 0; 0 0]`.

Comment: Looks like you can RTFM! :-) +1.